# Function does not return any errors, but does not work once I edited the code

Tags: javascript, function

So the task is :
1. If the argument c is passed and it is a function, it is executed after calling the sum function.
2. The function f must return the result of the function of argument c, if any, or the result of the function sum.

Here is my code.

```
function c(){
    return console.log('c is a function');
} 

function f (a = 2, b = 3, c){ 

    if(typeof c === 'function'){
        c();
    } else if (typeof c === 'undefined'){
        return;
    } else {
        function sum (a, b){ 
        return a + b; 
        }
    }
}

f(5, 10);
```

It stopped working once I added this line:

```
else if (typeof c === 'undefined'){
        return;
}
```

I would appreciate if you provide your pieces of advice as I am a newbie :)

Comment: What is the `else` branch supposed to do?

Comment: There's no `c` in `f(5, 10);`, hence `f` stops in your `else if` branch returning `undefined`

Comment: You're defining the sum function inside the f function but you're not calling it anywhere

Comment: @Andreas Hello, thanks for your reply. I added else if branch to check if c is not passed. It is not passed in f(5, 10) and it should return the result of function sum. But it just stopped :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it should be as expected?

When using that function without the 3 parameter, the `c` param is undefined.

You can verify that by logging it

```
...
else if (typeof c === 'undefined'){
        console.log(typeof c)
        return;
    }
...
```

But there doesn't seem to be a need for that check.

F.e.

```js
function c(){
return 'c is a function';
} 

function f (a = 2, b = 3, f = null){ 

if(typeof f === 'function'){
    return f(a, b);
} 
 else {
    return a + b;
}
}

console.log(f(5, 10))

console.log(f(5, 10, 999))

console.log(f(6, 10, c))
```

Comment: Thx.  But this is probably the first time I see that someone passes a function to a function like that.  Well, it happens with the asynchronous callback functions of course, but that's different.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
function sum(a, b){ 
    return a + b; 
}

function f (a = 2, b = 3, c){ 
    if(typeof c === 'function'){
        return c( sum(a,b) );
    } else {
        return sum(a,b);
    }
}

var num1 = f(5, 10 );
var num2 = f(5, 10, ( num ) => num * 5 );
```

Here num1 gives you 15, and num2 gives you 75

Comment: It is something like my tasks, but is still different I believe.

Comment: I have given funtion:

        function f (a, b, c) { 
              function sum (a, b) { 
              return a + b; 
              } 
          }



My task is the following:
Rewrite it as follows:

1.If arguments a and b are not passed, they are equal by default to 2 and 3, respectively.
2.If the argument c is passed and it is a function, then it is executed after calling the sum function.
3.The function f must return the result of the function of argument c, if any, or the result of the function sum.

Comment: Ah! I see, thanks for sharing that. I will figure out how to return the result to console. you are the best :)

Comment: Would you please explain what does the ( num ) => num * 5 part does?

Comment: It's just a function, it is equivalent to `function( num ) { return num * 5 }`